# Make thumbs scroll one at a time in SwiperJS

Tags: javascript, web-frontend, swiper.js

Trying to make a simple carousel with an associated thumbs carousel under it:

```js
    // Thumbs
    const galleryThumbs = new Swiper(thumbsElement, {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      slidesPerView: 4,
      scrollbar: true,
      breakpoints: {
        768: {
          slidesPerView: 8,
        },
      },
    });

    // Slides
    const galleryTop = new Swiper(top, {
      spaceBetween: 10,
      effect: "fade",
      loop: true,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
      },
      multipleActiveThumbs: false,
      thumbs: {
        swiper: galleryThumbs,
      },
    });
```

This is working as described, but I have a problem:

When one scrolls to the next image using the navigation arrows, and the corresponding thumbnail is out of sight, the thumbnails scroll in group(by the amount described in the `slidesPerView` setting). I'm looking for a way for it to scroll just by one, as it does when scrolling with the back arrow.